# Can a virus in a Virtual Machine leak to the host?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virus

I am looking to use a Windows 10 virtual machine using VirtualBox to download and scan software before I install it onto my main PC.

Is there a possibility that a virus could leak from the VM into the host OS?

I looked at similar questions and the answers mentioned isolating it from the network. But what I'm doing requires network access. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need network connectivity, then it is just like any real machine.

Open Windows Defender settings (task bar, right side, possibly a hidden icon).

Go to Virus and Threat protection, scan options, and do a full Defender Offline Scan.

The Offline Scan should eliminate (quarantine) any viruses.

If nothing is found, then there is likely nothing wrong and you can continue using your virtual machine.

Comment: If WD finds a virus it quarantines it. Windows Defender is top notch and after V1809 comes with EMET. So (a) you do not really need another AV (if that is what you meant) and (b) no virus will get on your regular PC.  Scanning the VM is just like scanning a real machine - if nothing is found, there is very likely not a virus.

Answer (score -1):

Ys it can,If you download ransomwares like Jigsaw see this vid https://youtu.be/YN14KYOa0O8?t=371

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.